# Dependencies (RxJS) not being installed from package.json in Dockerfile?

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, npm

I am trying to containerize my app to deploy it to GCP. I've been doing some local testing before getting any triggers setup and for some reason, rxjs (maybe others as well) are not being installed despite being listed in the package.json.

In my Dockerfile, it errors on the build step because it cannot find the rxjs module (`RUN ls node_modules` shows that it's just not there even after installation). I have explicitly tried adding `RUN npm install rxjs`, but even that does not work. When I do that, I get a bunch of other errors about not being able to find modules being staged by npm. This happens both on my local machine and on the Cloud Run instance I am trying to build / deploy.

Before anyone mentions it, I've tried deleting my package-lock.json and doing a fresh install - this has the exact same result. When I actually build it directly from the command-line, it all works. It seems more like an issue with the Docker container.

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:12.18-alpine AS dev

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install --only=dev

COPY . .

RUN npm run build:prod

FROM node:12.18-alpine AS prod

ARG NODE_ENV=production
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install --only=prod

COPY . .

COPY --from=dev /usr/src/app/dist ./dist

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "ui",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:prod": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.1.7",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.7",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.7",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.7",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/material": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.7",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.7",
    "@ngstack/code-editor": "^1.0.0",
    "angular-markdown-editor": "^2.0.2",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "ngx-markdown": "^10.1.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.901.7",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.1.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.7",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.36",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3"
  }
}
```

Output from `docker build --rm .`

```
$ docker build --rm .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  868.4kB
Step 1/15 : FROM node:12.18-alpine AS dev
 ---> 18f4bc975732
Step 2/15 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> be5e328970e5
Step 3/15 : COPY package*.json ./
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 634457d1a251
Step 4/15 : RUN npm install --only=dev
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4e8cd1472043
Step 5/15 : COPY . .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 423a944a84c2
Step 6/15 : RUN npm run build:prod
 ---> Running in b68a5b25ff84

> ui@1.0.0 build:prod /usr/src/app
> ng build --prod

Unknown error: Error: Cannot find module 'rxjs'
Require stack:
- /usr/src/app/node_modules/inquirer/lib/ui/prompt.js
- /usr/src/app/node_modules/inquirer/lib/inquirer.js
- /usr/src/app/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/analytics.js
- /usr/src/app/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command-runner.js
- /usr/src/app/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/cli/index.js
- /usr/src/app/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/init.js
- /usr/src/app/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! ui@1.0.0 build:prod: `ng build --prod`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ui@1.0.0 build:prod script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-09-08T19_47_14_999Z-debug.log
The command '/bin/sh -c npm run build:prod' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

> Step 4/15 : RUN npm install --only=dev
> ---> Using cache

As long as you have some issues with making build I would suggest you to make each of it without cache. Just add `--no-cache` to be sure that `npm install` was really called.

```
docker build --no-cache -t mybuild:v1 .
```

Comment: This resulted in the same error for me. I should've added this to the question (updated now), but even when I try a remote test build, GCP throws the same error at the exact same point.

Comment: Okey. Another idea. When you run npm install with flag `--only=dev` you are installing all packages under **devDependencies**. It means that **dependencies** where you have e.g. rxjs won't be installed, therefore you can't successfully call `npm run build:prod`. You will be able to make build after adding **dependencies** to your dockerized app. I see two possbilities:
1. try to move `RUN npm run build:prod` after `RUN npm install --only=prod`  
or  
2. use `npm install` without flag, so all dependencies will be fulfilled

Comment: This totally makes sense. I opted for the second solution, and it worked for me. Although I'm getting another error on the deploy step of the process, my original question is answered. Thank you!